# Handle Image Metadata Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift, metadata, swift2, ios9

I have a code to save a picture in Swift (1.1) and since IOS 9 i try to change it for swift 2.0 but after 3 days i can not ...

So it's a juste a simple function get metadata and function get this, update this and create new image with this. Works fine with xCode 6.2 and Swift (1.1)

So if you can help me please :s

```
import ImageIO

func savePicture(data: NSData) {
    var img: CGImageRef

    if let source = CGImageSourceCreateWithData(data, nil) {

        var metadata = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(source, 0, nil)! as Dictionary
        let width = CGFloat(metadata[kCGImagePropertyPixelWidth] as NSNumber)
        let height = CGFloat(metadata[kCGImagePropertyPixelHeight] as NSNumber)
        let reso = width * height


        metadata[kCGImageDestinationLossyCompressionQuality as String] = self.jpegQuality

        var tiff:NSMutableDictionary = metadata[kCGImagePropertyTIFFDictionary] as NSMutableDictionary
        tiff.setValue("Pictures", forKey: kCGImagePropertyTIFFModel)
        var exif:NSMutableDictionary = metadata[kCGImagePropertyExifDictionary] as NSMutableDictionary
        exif.setValue("Pictures", forKey: kCGImagePropertyExifLensModel)

        let gps:NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()
        metadata[kCGImagePropertyGPSDictionary] = gps
        gps.setValue(self.loc["lat"], forKey: kCGImagePropertyGPSLatitude)
        gps.setValue(self.loc["lng"], forKey: kCGImagePropertyGPSLongitude)
        self.dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
        gps.setValue(self.dateFormatter.stringFromDate(NSDate()), forKey: kCGImagePropertyGPSTimeStamp)
        self.dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy:MM:dd"
        gps.setValue(self.dateFormatter.stringFromDate(NSDate()), forKey: kCGImagePropertyGPSDateStamp)

        if (reso > self.desiredRes) {
            let ratio = reso / self.desiredRes
            metadata[kCGImageSourceThumbnailMaxPixelSize as String] = max(width, height) / sqrt(ratio)
            metadata[kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailFromImageIfAbsent as String] = true

            img = CGImageSourceCreateThumbnailAtIndex(source, 0, metadata)

        } else {
            img = CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex(source, 0, metadata)
        }


        let uti = "public.jpeg"
        var d = NSMutableData()
        var dest: CGImageDestinationRef = CGImageDestinationCreateWithData(d, uti, 1, nil)
        CGImageDestinationAddImage(dest, img, metadata)
        CGImageDestinationFinalize(dest)

        d.writeToFile(self._makePicName(), atomically: false)


    }

    //        debug purpose: show that metadata have been saved
    //        let d = NSData(contentsOfFile: self.paths.last!)
    //        if let t = CGImageSourceCreateWithData(d, nil) {
    //            let again = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(t, 0, nil) as Dictionary
    //            println(again)
    //        }

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        for dlg in self.delegate {
            dlg.didFinishSavingPhoto?()
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: In Xcode, activate menu `Edit > Convert > To Latest Swift Syntax`. It will make most of the necessary modifications.

Comment: Cannot subscript a value of type 'Dictionary<NsError, AnyObject> with a index of type CFString

Comment: I try ... And no success

Comment: This is a picture with errors : http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/474500Sanstitre2.jpg

Comment: declare ur metadata dictionary as [String: Anyobject] instead of just as dictionary

Comment: I test and no work .... someone have an idea ?

Comment: @MathieuLeTyrant I am dealing exactly with the same problem have you found a way to declare your Dictionary

Comment: Hi, for fix the problem i use : let metadata  = NSMutableDictionary(dictionary: CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(source, 0, nil)!)